# Lots of dpkg errors when doing upgrade on raspian, how to fix?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, raspbian

I just attempted update and upgrade on my raspberry pi 3 and get the following errors:

```
Setting up console-setup-linux (1.188) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 installed console-setup-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dbus (1.12.12-1) ...
A reboot is required to replace the running dbus-daemon.
Please reboot the system when convenient.
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
 installed dbus package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up alsa-utils (1.1.7-1) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package alsa-utils (--configure):
 installed alsa-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
 bluez depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ntp (--configure):
 installed ntp package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up policycoreutils (2.8-1) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package policycoreutils (--configure):
 installed policycoreutils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up rsync (3.1.3-1) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package rsync (--configure):
 installed rsync package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of selinux-policy-default:
 selinux-policy-default depends on policycoreutils (>= 2.7); however:
  Package policycoreutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package selinux-policy-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up sudo (1.8.26-2) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package sudo (--configure):
 installed sudo package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
 dbus
 alsa-utils
 bluez
 ntp
 policycoreutils
 rsync
 selinux-policy-default
 sudo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This happened when I left update running on a screen session and forgot about it for some time, then came back and it was showing a changelog (or something like this) which a scrolled through and quit. Can anyone say how to fix my system?

Here's what's in my sources.list, is this correct?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# added to allow certbot installation (see
# https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2673
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi
deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable
```

if I do `cat /etc/os-release` I get something unexpected, I expected to see jessie?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux buster/sid"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I edited the sources files as suggested in a comment. Now they contain:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# added to allow certbot installation (see
# https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2673
#deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi
#deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable
```

I then ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. This produced the following error:

```
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 46385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_215-17+deb8u8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:armhf (215-17+deb8u8) over (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Setting up libudev1:armhf (215-17+deb8u8) ...
(Reading database ... 46385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_215-17+deb8u8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking udev (215-17+deb8u8) over (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-1) ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u8) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So now only one package appears to have an error. I thought perhaps I could just reinstall this package, so I tried the following:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall udev
```

but got the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install --reinstall udev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  checkpolicy g++-4.9 imagemagick-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapol4 libargon2-0 libasprintf0c2 libauparse0 libbabeltrace1 libbind9-90 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libclass-method-modifiers-perl libcpan-changes-perl
  libcryptsetup12 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdns100 libevent-2.1-6 libfastjson4 libfile-slurp-perl libicu57 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libisl10 libjim0.75 libjs-excanvas liblognorm5 liblua5.1-0 liblwres90 liblz4-1 libmagickcore-6.q16-5
  libmagickwand-6.q16-5 libmariadbclient18 libmpfr4 libonig2 libperl4-corelibs-perl libprocps7 libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libqdbm14 libqpol1 librole-tiny-perl libssl1.0.2 libstdc++-4.9-dev libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl
  libvpx1 libxapian30 linux-base lsof php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline python-audit python-ipy python-pyasn1 python-selinux python-semanage python-sepolgen python-sepolicy python-setools python3-pyinotify python3.4
  python3.4-minimal samba-common selinux-policy-default setools sgml-base tcpd xml-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for udev:armhf
```

Some googling revealed [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=126012) where they have the same error, i.e.

```
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
```

and fix it by removing this group by commenting it out in `/etc/group`, then running `addgroup --system input`. I've no idea if this is a good thing to do.

Comment: It seems you may have [Broken Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) ... comment out `deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable` along with `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi`  And maybe you'll be able to `apt-get update` back to something like a sensible set of libraries / system programs.

Comment: @RubberStamp, thanks I did what you suggested, but the problem remains, with the same errors. Should I try reinstalling the offending packages? Also, is `apt-get autoremove` a safe thing to do?

Comment: @RubberStamp, I take it back, I commented out the wrong thing before, now I did what you actually said and the error is slightly different, I have edited the question.

Comment: once upgraded Debian (or derivatives) don't downgrade to a lower package version. it's possible to force it (`man apt preferences` set pin-priority to >= 1001) but it can break it further because downgrades aren't supported

Comment: @A.B, thanks, is there any way to save the situation?

Comment: consider it broken and consider reinstallation. anyway first backup important data. now you can try and upgrade it completely to testing: put back the testing url and try apt-get -f dist-upgrade . If it fails, reinstall...

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` in this case is not a good idea if you want to save the currently installed system.... @A.B  ... an individual package can be installed at a given version level by setting the version like this... `apt-get install package=version` ... so, it's possible to downgrade a package or two if needed in an *Oops!* moment. ... I've had several of those in the past. ... However, I agree that the system is likely beyond repair in a reasonable amount of time. So, save important non-system files and reinstall is probably best.

Comment: the danger of downgrading is when two related packages "exchange" a file during upgrade. this file can be lost on downgrade. when knowing what to expect it's possible to manage it (with a lot of blind --reinstall as a 2nd pass) else .. breaks a bit more

Comment: Sigh, backup and reinstall it is then. Thanks for the help.